# Android logcat full of "QcrilMsgTunnelSocket"

Tags: android, logcat

my logcat is full of this error-message:

```
QcrilMsgTunnelSocket        IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
```

it is appearing like every 5 seconds.
i got a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4 (ported from Nexus 5)

Does anybody know where this may come from?

Comment: Did you ever find where this is coming from? Google isn't helping much...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a project I was working on. I forgot to add Internet permissions to my Android Manifest file. After that it fixed that error, hope it helps.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

It's the phone app

[image]

Very weird, I have XPosed and GravityBox installed though so maybe they're doing something

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the modem library that the phone uses. The library is looking for a modem chip that doesn't exist, and throws the error. It is annoying, but shouldn't be causing any issues.

I found my information on [this forum](http://mydragonboard.org/community/hw-sw-8074/qcrilmsgtunnelsocket-io-exception-with-sdk-1-1-0/)

They say that you can remove the qcrilmsgtunnel.apk, which will stop the error messages, although I personally wouldn't recommend removing system APKs from your rom.
The instructions from the forum are as follows:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm system/app/qcrilmsgtunnel.apk
```

This can be done from a phone connected to a PC via ADB in the Android SDK, or from a Terminal Emulator app, however, if you are finding this message an annoyance, you probably knew that already. The location of your 'qcrilmsgtunnel.apk' may differ on your device.

I noticed the errors on my Galaxy S4. I have not tried removing said apk, but if you did, I am curious as to any side-effects, and you are welcome to comment below with your results and device.